# css drop down menu displays as a bullet list in IE8

Tags: css

I created a dropdown CSS menu and it is working in Firefox but not in IE8. I need for it to work in all browsers, can someone help?. I don't have a URL yet, just creating the site in an old version of Frontpage.

Here is the CSS script:

```
#cssmenu{ height:37px; display:block; padding:0; margin:20px auto;  border:1px  
solid;     border-radius:5px; } 
#cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; 
display:block; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; padding:12px 
20px; font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-
decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); } 
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; border-right:1px solid; 
top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; 
right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f; padding-
bottom:13px; padding-top:13px; top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; 
position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 
5px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; 
position:relative;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; 
padding:8px 20px; font:10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-
decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 



#cssmenu, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{ background:#97c20a; background:-moz- 
linear-gradient(top,  #97c20a 0%, #8da408 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 
left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#97c20a), color-stop(100%,#8da408)); background:-
webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #97c20a 0%,#8da408 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient
(top,  #97c20a 0%,#8da408 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #97c20a 
0%,#8da408 100%); background:linear-gradient(top,  #97c20a 0%,#8da408 100%); 
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#97c20a', 
endColorstr='#8da408',GradientType=0 ); } 

#cssmenu{border-color:#647306;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{border-right:1px solid #647306; color:#fff;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{border-color:#c2f224;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover{background:#7fa208;}
```

I also tried creating a javascript menu but the links wouldn't work, if someone knows the code i can manually enter it.  example line below:

```
stm_aix("p1i4","p1i0",[0,"Flash Software"],0,20);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css you want to make sure that both your unordered list element "UL" and your list items "LI"s have this css applied to them to remove the bullet in IE8

```
list-style: none;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
```

i would try adding this css specifically to your stylesheet:

```
 #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li{
     list-style: none;
     list-style-image: none;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
```

if that fails i would suggest trying a CSS reset such as [the very popular Reset provided by Erik Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, it didn't seem to work, in firefox i see the navigation bar and the drop down menu appears when i hover over, but in IE8 there is no nav bar, just a list with sub lists

Comment: any chance you could post the url and i could take a look? are you using a css reset or have you tried to add one?  depending on the other styles in your stylesheet or the position of the styles you may have to add  "!important" tags to the css like such    "list-style: none !important;"

Comment: the site is not online yet, i tried the reset and it took away the bullets but there is no nav menu, I created this menu  using http://cssmenumaker.com